# Can I make a timeline bar graph with two types of data in Excel?

Tags: excel

I used the search function and could not find an answer for this.

I have data that looks like the following:

[image]

I would like one bar graph with the date on the x-axis and "Inches" on the y-axis, but I would like the color of the bar to change depending on the 'Type' of Y data. When I try to use the charts under the "insert" tab, this does not work. It makes one huge plot with all of the information crammed into the x-axis. I am fairly new to this sort of thing, however, and could be doing things wrong.

Any advice would be hugely appreciated. Please let me know if there is any information that I can add to make this question more helpful. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am new to asking questions like this, if anything is done incorrectly, please let me know and I will try to fix it. Thanks so much for your patience.

Comment: You'll get exactly what you want by reformatting your data a bit. Create three columns: Date, Irrigation, and Precipitat. The values for Irrigation and Precipitat fall into those two columns. Then just select your data and insert the type of chart you want. An excellent reference for charts is always Jon Peltier, especially [Good Chart Data](https://peltiertech.com/good-chart-data/)

Comment: @PeterT Hey Peter, thanks a ton for the help. This seems like a great step, but because Irrigation and Precipitation aren't on the same date, the information ends up not lining up. Do you know a workaround for this? Thanks again.

Comment: If there is a date with one or the other data set missing, then it's missing. If you need a different grouping of the data (e.g. total by week) then you'll have to create a helper column -- or even better, create a pivot table and pivot chart.

Comment: A key part of this dataset is that Irrigation and Precipitation are never on the same date. I think I could be phrasing things better by saying that I'm hoping to have what would essentially be two bar graphs on the same x-axis. So for the overall time period of this dataset, it'd be nice to have bars for Irri and bars for Precip on the same plot. Despite being from different individual dates, they still follow the same timeline if that makes sense. So sorry if it's hard to articulate what I'm hoping for here-- please let me know if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you organize your data into three columns: Date, Irrigation, and Precipitation.

[image]

Then from the Insert ribbon, select a 2D chart. The default chart settings produces a chart like this:

[image]